# What is this succulent-like plant, and how can I revive it?

Tags: identification, succulents

I got this plant as a gift last summer (first picture) and it dried up in the winter. Now it's grown back to some extent (second picture).

At first, I thought it's a kind of ice rose succulent but I'm not sure.

Any help on what it is and how I can revive it would be appreciated.

[image: picture from last summer]
[image: now]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Crassula Capitella or also known as Camp Fire or Red Pagoda. It prefers full sun exposure. Use the 'soak and dry' method of watering. Meaning, water the plant if the medium is dry making sure that the water reaches the bottom part of the pot. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the leaves are green suggests it is not getting enough light.

The basic color of the plant is red, which is masked by green chlorophyll. In brighter light, the plant doesn't need to produce so much chlorophyll for photosynthesis and the red color is visible.

Also, if you think it doesn't look very nice with the shoots growing horizontally, you could use each set of leaves as a cutting and get four plants instead of one. Just cut the old stem into segments and plant each one with the stem horizontal in the ground and the leaves vertical. Water the pots before you plant the cuttings and do *not* water them again until they start to grow, or they may rot and die.